# Users Unable to Open Public Folders in Outlook

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

Using Exchange 2010, no changes have been done (updates, DB Change, NOTHING) we have two DB's for Exchange which I will refer them as DB1 and DB2. All mailboxes on DB1 cant see public folders via outlook client but can see them in OWA. All DB2 mailboxes have no issues.

This is the error I get when mailbox on DB1 try accessing Public Folders
[Clientside Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txHd1.jpg)

When I login to where DB1 is located and Open Exchange Control Panel and try updating hierarchy, I get this second error
[Update Hierarchy Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nYQL.jpg)

Only Chance in AD that has occurred since was a user was disabled... Any help that can point me in the right direction to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the event log on the server? We saw similar access issues when we had database issues on our server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is replica of this Public Folder on other servers.